# With Rules, how do I use variables with Calculate and Set a value actions?

Tags: 7, commerce, rules

Let's say I have an Entity with a custom integer field added. Let's call the field Global Total (field_global_total)

On some event, I want to

- get the existing value of that field and store it in a variable
- get the value of another integer field (from another entity) and store that in a variable
- add the two variables together
- save that sum as the new value of "Global Total"

Ultimately I want to learn this generically so I can build more complex rules. For example, I don't know how to create a variable, but when I do, is that variable confined to the scope of that rule? Or can I pass it around to any subsequent rule? And if I can, how do I access it in other rules?

But if it helps, this is my specific use case.

My goal is, in Commerce, I have Product A. Product A has an integer field called "Total Sold to Date" (field_total_sold_to_date). Let's say that the current value is 15.

**Event**

Item is added to cart. Quantity field is updated to 20. **User checks out**.

**Condition**

Entity has field

**Action**

-- get Quantity value and store it in variable 'this_quantity'

-- get Total_sold_to_date value and store it in 'ttstd'

-- add the two together

-- save the entity so that the sum is the new value of the product's field_total_sold_to_date value

Please note that I do not want to use an extra module like compute fields or math or commerce reports. I feel like this can be done out of the box. Thanks!

Comment: I'm having trouble finding tutorials or complete documentation about the Calculate a Value and Set a Value selectors for Rules. If you have any, please post them here in the comments.

Comment: built components, first component, calculate anything you neeed, and return result, second component, same thing, now in your rule call your comonents, since both returned a value, in rules do: a+b=c

Comment: search in this tutorial, its easy, goog luck https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QL1Rp69Lq80&list=PL84B6FFA4F7ACAD57